# How to remove an object from an ArrayController when the content is fetched by "Content Array"-Binding?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, binding, nsarraycontroller

I have the following setup using Core Data:

Nib1:
A WindowController with two custom views, that loads  the views from Nib2 and Nib3.

Nib2:
NSTreeController with an custom class, that has an property to fetch some child objects by selection, called *selectedAssetsBySelection*. The TreeController prepares its content with CoreData.

Nib3:
It is a NSArrayController with the "Content Array" binding bound to *selectedAssetsBySelection* of the NSTreeController of Nib2.

The Array in Nib3 is notified about selection changes by

```
[contextViewController bind:@"selectedAssets" toObject:naviViewController.treeController withKeyPath:@"selectedAssetsBySelection" options:nil];
```

within Nib1, the window controller.

Everything works fine and when I select an object within the TreeController in Nib2 the array in Nib3 is updated and when I change the title of an object in Nib3 it is also persisted.

All Array Controllers are also bound to the correct managed Object Context.

Now to the problem:
When I delete an object via *remove*-Action of Array Controller in Nib3 I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS-Error.

[image]

Anybody a clue?

Best regards, hijolan

Comment: Yeah!!!! I made it... ;)

I had to check these two checkboxes on the arraycontroller in Nib3:

![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng3lZ.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah!!!! I made it... ;)

I had to check these two checkboxes on the arraycontroller in Nib3:

[image]